# Error al querer llamar desde Python la base de datos (SQLite3)

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tengo este código en Python:

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

square = lambda n : n*n 

conn = sqlite3.connect("Northwind.db")
conn.create_function("square",1,square)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT * FROM Products
    ''')

results = cursor.fetchall()

results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

cursor.close()
conn.close()

print(results_df)
```

Y al ejecutarlo me marca este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\alexi\OneDrive\Documentos\SQLite3\UDF.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute('''
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Products.
```

La base de datos que estoy trabajando es una de *Northwind* (para practicar) y sí tiene una tabla llamada `Products`, y sí tiene datos ingresados.

Soy principiante, apenas estoy aprendiendo, pero por este error me estoy estancando. Ya busqué soluciones por otros lados y no las encontré.
También les proporciono la base de datos que estoy trabajando: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Database_Examples/Northwind/SQLite
(Sí tiene las sangrias, solo que al publicarlo no aparecen)

Comment: Creé la BD, Northwind.db, tal como lo indica en la URL, le cargué los datos, puse el script .py en la misma ubicación de la BD, copié el mismo código en el script y al ejecutar anduvo correctamente. Sale la lista de productos y al final `[77 rows x 6 columns]`. Algo no estás haciendo bien. Desde un [editor SQLite](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) verifica que verdaderamente se haya creado la tabla `Products`, recuerda que en algunos editores tienes que seleccionar todo el código para que ejecute todas las sentencias SQL.

Comment: Al final lo pude resolver, tuve que especificar exactamente donde se encontraba la base de datos aquí la respuesta: conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/alexi/OneDrive/Documentos/SQLite3/Northwind.db') y así sí funcionó. Igualmente, muchas gracias. La verdad.

Comment: En cuanto sepa como calificar lo haré, hermano. Muchas gracias. (Soy nuevo en esta plataforma)